# Shim to make PCB section thicker

Tags: pcb, usb, pcb-design, esp8266, adhesives

[image]

For my latest product, I have designed a USB ESP8266 dev kit for hobbyists (http://rxtx.weebly.com). The theory is that it fits into a USB-A plug directly through the PCB - hence why I am gold plating the traces.

But I noticed in several other posts that the PCB needs to be at least 2.0mm thick, but PCB houses charge a lot for that thickness - thus why I am sticking to 1.6mm. To compensate for this 0.4mm thickness, what kind of shim would I need - I only need it to cover an area of 10mm by 8mm and it won't be in contact with any rails - plastic, but which kind? Where could I source it cheaply?

The PCB material is FR-4 (ShengYi Tg140). Also, can you advise me on what glue type to use as I am new to adhesives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: YOu need to specify the board thickness you want... shims wont work

Comment: Apparently we are talking about two different things here.  There is too much confusion here without a diagram

Comment: Added one now - if its not called a 'shim', then I suppose just a plastic 'plate' to increase the thickness so that it fits.

Comment: BY the time you add the cost of making the shim the right size and the labor costs of glueing it in place your cost of a thicker board is probably trivial. PLus the reliability is better with a thicker board.

Comment: Can you specify both a soldermask and solid silkscreen on the backside of the board under the connector?  It might help cover the remaining 400um.

Comment: @Trevor_G That might be true but the price for 50 boards jumps from about $15 to about $60 for the thicker size - surely just for a prototype batch that's a bit unnecessary? I will certainly be using the thicker board option if the board proves functional, but I suppose for a small batch I'm producing myself, shimming would be the best option.

Comment: @BryanBoettcher Can I specify that the silkscreen layer needs to be 400um thick from allpcb.com?? Because that might just solve it...

Comment: That is a big difference, try a different board house... or 2mm may be a bastard size.. what's the closest they can do

Comment: BTW.. what is the ACTUAL specs on the connector standard. You have not indicated that...

Comment: @Trevor_G 1.6mm is the closest, then there's 2.4mm - the same price as the 2.0mm. I was told allpcb.com were one of the cheaspest PCB board houses worldwide... (I'm in the UK)

Comment: 12mm x 12mm x 2.0mm. This is actually the first time I'm looking at that, and the first time I actually noticed that the connector is a square....

Comment: WHats the tollerances though

Comment: + or - 0.1mm for all the lengths, including thickness.

Comment: what about using something like this?  ... https://www.amazon.com/uxcell-Right-Angle-Socket-Connector/dp/B00FH7TF0M .... also, using only the shell may solve the issue

Comment: @jsotola Yeah, it's just that I've never used the PCB itself as a connector before, and so I didn't want to use a ready-made through-hole male connector. (I actually used Sparkfun USB-A-PCB design from their library on Eagle)

Comment: you could save some money by ordering 100  1.0mm boards, 50 of which are completely blank, or have a ground plane and glue two together to make a 2.0mm board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an XY, but I'll still attempt to address the question itself.

To increase the thickness of a 1.6mm board to 2.0mm required by USB (although it probably doesn't need it) in prototype-scale, attach a PVC shim to the underside of the board.  Use McMaster 87875K72 and a guillotine-style paper cutter to cut strips, then cut further into squares.  Fasten them to the underside of the PCB with CA glue.  An alignment jig will help, and the whole process will take easily under an hour.  I can see you hitting upwards of 10 boards/min once the jig is set up.

Answer (score 2):

To compensate for 0.4 mm thickness, you obviously need a 0.4 mm non-conductive shim, you said it yourself, minus thickness of glue.

However, USB specification explicitly define all connectors with conductive housing. It is done for a reason of protection of USB signals against ESD events. Every time people plug in your device, the built charge on the dongle and on the entire body will go into power (and possibly signal) pins. The metal housing on USB connectors is meant to divert the discharge currents into a separate shield. This consideration goes both ways, to host, and to your device, since D+/D- are well exposed to a touch.

To make things right, you better use dedicated PCB-mounted USB plugs, they are not very expensive these days. [Like this one](https://www.ebay.com/p/15he-20-Pcs-USB-Mae-TPE-a-Port-Rlight-Ange-4-pin-DIP-Jack-Connector/1669552457).

[image]

This will make things right.

Alternatively, if you continue to make naked connectors, you can build your PCB in a place that can make specified thickness for you, 2 mm for example, for extra price. Look at PCBWay.com.